# K8s Nginx Ingress controller RewriteRule

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I need to move Apache config to K8s Nginx ingress controller and I stucked on this part:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/motos>
  RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/index.php(.*)$ /motos/auto_portal/index.php$1
  RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/private/?(.*)$ /motos/auto_portal/private/$1
  RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/scripts/?(.*)$ /motos/auto_portal/scripts/$1
  RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/graphics/?(.*)$ /motos/auto_portal/graphics/$1
</Directory>
```

Looks like I can define it in annotation, but I can`t find good example how I can do it.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: motos-site
  annotations:
    [looks like here should be defined rules?]
spec:
  rules:
  - host: [some-host.com]
    http:
      paths:
      - path: [?]
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some rest, these rules related to dir and not related to traffic rules rewrite :/
K8s Nginx ingress does not involved in this process.